# Why Pycharm - jupyter consume so much RAM?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ram

I have been working with python using the IDE of Pycharm and at the same time using its jupyter interface. I don't know why It consumes a huge amount of RAM, previously I was using 8 GB of RAM and I update my computer putting an extra 32 GB of RAM with this I thought that the message of `out of memory` was going to disappear but not.
That message is less frequent but it still appears. The programme starts to be slow and I have to wait a couple of minutes until the RAM is freer.

[image]

Comment: PyCharm consumes a lot of RAM in general. If you have some directories with data in the project try to mark them as excluded. Or try using a more lightweight solution like JupyterLab for a few days to compare if the issue is in notebooks or in the IDE.

Comment: This 'question' can't really be 'answered' in terms of how stack overflow typically works. There's no info for how to replicate anything. There's no code or data. From my perspective it could just be that you have an object that you keep adding to infinitely and never clean up. Memory leak?

Comment: It depends on how big are your data, and it seems you doesn't delete old data (which it is good for huge data, `del` keyword). Try `Spyder` (sometime it is better: it will not read and try to interpret data (in data console) at every command). If you still have the error, the data is the problem. Do in batches, split algorithms into sub-models in separate files. Do not use jupyter, but just python (ev. ipython): on large data you are already losing interactivity. Just do jupyter on small subset to prepare full calculations.

Comment: Also, (in my experience) it ignores the max heap size setting under Help/Change Memory Settings.